Unable to Resolve DNS for api.huggingface.co on Ubuntu 24.04 - Node.js Application Issue
I'm working on a Node.js application hosted on Ubuntu 24.04, integrating with Hugging Face's API for fine-tuning models. However, I’ve encountered a persistent DNS resolution issue when trying to connect to api.huggingface.co.
Steps I’ve Taken:

Updated /etc/resolv.conf - Set nameservers to Google’s DNS servers (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4).
Flushed DNS cache - Restarted NetworkManager to clear the cache.
Tested DNS Resolution - Ran ping, dig, and nslookup for api.huggingface.co. All return either No address associated with hostname or fail to resolve the address.

Diagnostics:
dig and nslookup don’t retrieve an IP address for api.huggingface.co, despite using Google DNS.
I also checked my /etc/resolv.conf configuration to ensure no overriding configurations exist.
Additional Details:

OS: Ubuntu 24.04
Node.js Version: 18.19.1
Network: Local network, tested via Ethernet
Relevant Code Repository:
Here’s my GitHub repository with the code: GitHub Repository Link.
Key files to review are:

Backend Logic: /backend/server.js - Main server file handling API calls.
Job Queue Management: /backend/models/jobs.js - Job queue for handling fine-tuning requests.
Content Security Policy: Configured in /backend/server.js.



What could be preventing DNS resolution specifically for api.huggingface.co on this setup? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

api.huggingface.co doesn't exist according to any public domain servers

The correct DNS name is probably api-inference.huggingface.co according to their documentation: https://huggingface.co/docs/api-inference/en/getting-started
Another good debugging technique to try before reconfiguring your server is to try resolving the same domain using dig on your local machine or in a public lookup service like MXToolbox.

If you think it's the server, the response from dig can tell you a bit about what might be wrong.
For instance, in this response you can see status: NOERROR meaning that the query reached a server and the server responded without encountering any errors itself. Along with an ANSWER: 0 this usually means that there's nothing wrong with your setup, the DNS record just doesn't exist.
$ dig api.huggingface.co

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> api.huggingface.co
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 29888
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;api.huggingface.co.        IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
huggingface.co.     0   IN  SOA ns-919.awsdns-50.net. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 0

;; Query time: 86 msec
;; SERVER: fe80::1%6#53(fe80::1%6)
;; WHEN: Sun Oct 06 21:59:43 BST 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 131

When I try the same query with my wifi turned off I get this:
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> api.huggingface.co
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

If I try to query using canonical's nameservers I get status: REFUSED meaning these nameservers do not respond to requests for that domain. You can also see the lack of an aa flag in the flags section. This flag indicates that the server has been able to reach an authoritative source for the domain huggingface.co. These are not recursive nameservers, so they have not tried to reach an authoritative nameserver.
$ dig api.huggingface.co @ns1.canonical.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.amzn2.13 <<>> api.huggingface.co @ns1.canonical.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 58863
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;api.huggingface.co.        IN  A

;; Query time: 11 msec
;; SERVER: 185.125.190.65#53(185.125.190.65)
;; WHEN: Sun Oct 06 21:12:34 UTC 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 47

If your local resolving DNS server was broken in some way you may get status: SERVFAIL. (I don't have a broken resolving DNS server hanging around to produce an example.)
If I make a typo in the domain, I can get an answer more like this with status: NXDOMAIN which means that the domain does not exist. Dig cannot find any nameservers to ask about the api subdomain.
> dig api.puggingface.co

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.amzn2.13 <<>> api.puggingface.co
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 6107
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;api.puggingface.co.        IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
co.         619 IN  SOA ns1.cctld.co. admin.tldns.godaddy. 1728249137 1800 300 604800 1800

